# Making an image completely fill a div without tiling

Tags: html, css, image

I am fairly new to html/css and I am coding a website for my mom. (Live example here: http://jleblanc.pancakeapps.com/core.html) and for the life of me I can't get the photos at the bottom to fill their respective divs! Do any of you guys have an idea? I don't care if the image is cut off.

HTML

```
<div class="one">
    <article>
    </article>
</div>
<div class="two">
    <article>
    </article>
</div>
<div class="three">
    <article>
    </article>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.one {
    background:linear-gradient(rgba(255,0,0,0.45),rgba(255,0,0,0.45)),url(http://dash.ga.co/assets/firstcourse.jpg)
}

.two {
    background:linear-gradient(rgba(0,255,0,0.45),rgba(0,255,0,0.45)),url(http://dash.ga.co/assets/secondcourse.jpg)
}

.three {
    background:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,255,0.45),rgba(0,0,255,0.45)),url(http://dash.ga.co/assets/dessertcourse.jpg)
}
```

Comment: This is for someone's mom... No one down vote!

Comment: background-size: cover;

Comment: Put `margin: 0;` on the menu `<ul>` if you want to get rid of that white line under the menu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the CSS `background` property to set an image as your div's background. Try changing the `background-size` property:

```
.one {
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: I added background-size: cover; to .one but nothing happend, help?

Comment: Put `background-size: cover;` underneath the `background` in the css. Like: `background: xxx;
background-size: cover;`